# intcomma after widthratio in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to do "intcoma" after "widthratio" in the Django template.
I thought about it as below, but it doesn't work.

```html
{{ {% widthratio p.price 2 1 %}|intcomma }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the code in two parts

```
{% widthratio p.price 2 1 as price_ratio %}{{ price_ratio|intcomma }}
```